# How to use array and OR and AND in google spread sheet

Tags: arrays, formula

I've using this formula in google sheet to get the answer. Somewhere the logic is wrong please suggest. All logic i applied seams wrong

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(IF(OR(T:T="A",U:U="y"),1,0)))

B   X
A   y
A   x
A   y
B   x
```

Answer should be 2. Pls help where I am wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

There is some ambiguity in the question. In the formula you are using, there is an `OR`. So either first column should have 'A' or second one should have 'y'. Then, shouldn't the answer be 3?

The formula you are looking for in this case is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(ADD(IF(A:A="A",TRUE,FALSE),IF(B:B="y",TRUE,FALSE))>0,1,0)))
```

But if what you are looking for is AND, then the formula is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(MULTIPLY(IF(A:A="A",TRUE,FALSE),IF(B:B="y",TRUE,FALSE))>0,1,0)))
```

The basic concept here is that in an array expression, a simple boolean should be replaced `ADD` or `MULTIPLY` depending on if it is `OR` or `AND`